# Use jquery to display an image from a separate html document making it a bigger size

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I have a featured image which changes regularly on a remote html document.  For example the remote html document contains:

```
<html><body>
<img id="mainimage" width="40" height="40" src="myimg.jpg"  />
</body></html>
```

How can I load that image into my new document at a bigger size using javascript (jquery) (the image src changes dynamically so the jquery will scrape the img)

Let's say I want to put make it **100x100** between the following tag:

This works **but doesn't enlarge** the image to a bigger size:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$( "#biggerimg" ).load( "https://example.org #mainimage");
</script>
```

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
$( "#biggerimg" ).load( "https://example.org #mainimage.src"); //this doesn't get the source
```

Tried to change the size after it was loaded but this didn't work either:

```
$( "#biggerimg" ).load( "https://example.org #mainimg" , function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
  $( "#biggerimg img").css("height","100px");
  $( "#biggerimg img").css("width","100px");
});
```

Very close but for some reason I leave the site and come back and this works but it doesn't work every refresh:

```
$( "#biggerimg" ).load( "https://example.org #mainimg" , function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
  $( "#biggerimg img").attr("height","100px");
  $( "#biggerimg img").attr("width","100px");
});
```

Every time I refresh I get the following Console Error except 1 out of every 10 or so times there is no error but it shows the graphic larger:

```
myModule:229 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttr' of null
```

So close but not sure why it's not loading every time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Should adjust Width attribute on `$("#biggerimg img")` after it has loaded.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty I think I tried as you mentioned and posted the code you might have asked me to try which didn't resize the image. Can you post a code snippet if what I did was what you didn't mean. Thanks

Comment: Use `.attr()` instead of `.css()` in the edited code snippet at the end.

Comment: Thanks @Ryuno-Ki but that kind of worked. If I hit refresh a dozen times it will show up otherwise it shows the error I posted above. It's almost like the div element isn't fully loading before it tries to change the size of the width & height.

Comment: Hm, I guess, you aren't familiar with using a Debugger, are you? If you are, you could set a breakpoint in the jQuery code snippet from above within the browser DevTools to stop execution of JavaScript at that point to check your assumption. Otherwise it will be _very_ tricky to debug. Is the current solution „good enough”? If so, perhaps @Twisty could post an answer you can then accept.

Comment: Thanks Ryuno-Ki. I will have to figure out the debugger again which I haven't used in many years. I think the theory is good @Twisty. It's definitely some kind of timing issue and I would be interested in how Twisty can explain his answer.   If it looks close to what I was thinking, I will probably accept it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `src` attribute of the other `<img />` is `myimg.jpg`, you can point your `<img />` to https://example.org/myimg.jpg, i.e.

```
<img src="https://example.org/myimg.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
```

Be aware, that it likely appear blurred, since the browser will stretch that image. Also it might appear broken, if the other domain is taking it down (e.g. too much traffic because you are „slashdotting” them.

Comment: If you want to adjust it on the same page, adjust the `height` and `width` attribute to match the above.

Comment: Thanks @ryuno-ki but it's a little more complicated than that. That's assuming I know the image name. It's dynamic and I need it scraped using javascript or jquery.

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, chances are that you can't do that with JavaScript on the client side. In case you want to try, follow these steps: 1. Fetch the whole page using AJAX. 2. Pass this into `$.parseHTML` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/ context `null`) and search through it for `<img />` tags. Chances are you'll hit Cross-Origin-Request problems and need to use a server for mitigation.

Comment: Ah, wait, just looked up documentation for your `.load()` call: https://api.jquery.com/load/ Could be that this might be easier. Do you get a response to process here? Or are there errors logged to the console?

Comment: It's a local Joomla server (no cross platform issues) which uses Mosets Tree Component and I did get the load to load the graphic at 40x40 as per my .load() code listed above. I just want that image displayed on a different page at a different size inside a div element. Thanks